# Rails RSpec (beginner): Why is this test sometimes passing and sometimes not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a book database where books can have different book formats (hardcover, softcover etc).

I have factories with factory_bot.

The following spec just run through with an error - and then when I run it the second time, it worked. I have no idea where I need to start searching....

The error was:

```
  1) BookFormat displays the proper book format for a book with that format
     Failure/Error: expect(@book.book_format.name).to eq('Hardcover')
     
       expected: "Hardcover"
            got: "Not defined"
```

Here is the full spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BookFormat, type: :model do
  before(:all) do
    @book = create(:hobbit)
    @book_format_default = create(:not_defined)
  end

  it 'displays the proper book format for a book with that format' do
    expect(@book.book_format.name).to eq('Hardcover')
  end

  it 'should reassign to the fallback book_format if their book_format is deleted' do
    format = @book.book_format
    format.destroy
    expect(@book.reload.book_format.id).to eq(@book_format_default.id)
  end

  it 'should not let the fallback format be deleted' do
    format = @book_format_default
    format.destroy
    expect(format).to be_truthy
  end

end
```

Here is the corresponding factor for the book :hobbit:

```
  factory :hobbit, class: Book do
    title { 'The Hobbit' }
    year { 1937 }
    rating { 5 }
    condition { 4 }
    synopsis {  "<p>#{Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(number: 30).join(' ')}</p>" }
    association :book_format, factory: :hardcover
    association :user, factory: :me
    genres { [ create(:fiction) ] }

    after(:build) do |hobbit|
      hobbit.cover.attach(
        # rubocop:disable Rails/FilePath
        io: File.open(Rails.root.join('db', 'sample', 'images', 'cover-1.jpg')),
        # rubocop:enable Rails/FilePath
        filename: 'cover.jpg',
        content_type: 'image/jpeg'
      )
    end
  end
```

And here are the factories for book_formats:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :not_defined, class: BookFormat  do
    name { 'Not defined'}
    fallback { true }
  end
  factory :hardcover, class: BookFormat do
    name { 'Hardcover' }
  end

  factory :softcover, class: BookFormat do
    name { 'Softcover' }
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the whole output of the errors? Are you running only the failing one or among others? How're the relationships set in your models and migrations?

Comment: A book belongs to a book_format and a book_format has_many books. I can't reproduce the error any longer. I wonder whether it has to do with the order of the tests in the spec file // in how they are executed...

Comment: I'd advise you not to use `before(:all)` but `before(:each)` and avoid instance variables in your tests; if the error happens again you can save the seed for further debug

Answer (score 0):

What Sebastián Palma said. The problem is that you have with a high chance a random seed for for your specs, which is good. However in the beginning, of all specs you create once a book and then use this book, if the order of you specs are shuffled now, then the `book_format` of this book is deleted. So you should normally use `:each` instead of `:all`.

But better it would be to use `let` directly:

```
let(:book) { create(:book) }
let(:book_format_default) { create(:not_defined) }

it 'displays the proper book format for a book with that format' do
  expect(book.book_format.name).to eq('Hardcover')
end
```